# Static Body doesn't show where I put it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, box2d, game-physics

I am working on a small game that allows you to shoot a ball in a certain direction. The ball has to collide with a static body, and it does it just seems like the static body is trying to hide. The `UIView` shows up where I have placed it, but when I shoot the ball in that direction it collides with something invisible. Have I set the position using a wrong method?

```
-(void)createBoxWithView:(UIView *)physicalView{   
    b2BodyDef bd;
    bd.type = b2_staticBody;
    bd.userData = (__bridge void*)physicalView;

    CGPoint center = [physicalView center];

    bd.position.Set(center.x/PTM_RATIO, (self.view.frame.size.width - center.y)/PTM_RATIO);

    b2Body *body = world->CreateBody(&bd);

    b2PolygonShape box;
    box.SetAsBox(10/PTM_RATIO, 10/PTM_RATIO);

    b2FixtureDef fd;
    fd.shape = &box;

    body->SetType(b2_staticBody);

    body->CreateFixture(&fd);

}
```

Help much appreciated! 
Thanks!

Comment: Try looking at the debug draw display so you can see what is actually going on in the physics world. Otherwise you are blind.

Comment: you are subtracting centre.y by width, is that correct ?

Comment: @AlokRao my app runs in landscape orientation

Comment: @iforce2d can I set debug draw up without cocos2d?

Comment: Sure, see this: http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/setup-ios